# Multidimensional array IndexOutOfRange

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have this code:

```
int[, ,] data = new int[16, 32, 16];

for (int x = 0; x < data.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int z = 0; z < data.GetLength(1); z++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; x < data.GetLength(2); y++)
        {
            if (data[x, y, z] != 0)
            {
                // CODE
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
IndexOutOfRangeException: Array index is out of range.
(wrapper managed-to-managed) object:ElementAddr (object,int,int,int)

When: X=0 Y=32 Z=0

Comment: An array of size 32 can accommodate indexes from 0 to 31.

Comment: @JacobMattison new int[16, 30, 16] is Ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have a typo in the following statement:

```
for (int y = 0; x < data.GetLength(2); y++)
                ^
                |    
-----------------
```

Shouldn't it be `y < ...`?

Comment: But I still have the problem: S

Comment: @Dementor - The **same** problem?

Comment: YES, i found the error!
for (int z = 0; z < data.GetLength(2); z++)
for (int y = 0; x < data.GetLength(1); y++)

Comment: Good job. Missed that one.